# SQL to find IDs which never had a column value

Tags: sql, presto

Below is my data:

| ID | request_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

I need a query to fetch IDs that never had a request type of 1 (*e.g.* 2,3 from the previous table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(case when request_type = 1 then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `ID`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `ID` NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT `ID`
  FROM `my_table`
  WHERE `request_type` = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `1` is the lowest possible value:

```
select ID
from tab
group by ID
having min (request_type) > 1
```

Or more generic:

```
select ID
from tab
group by ID
having max(case when request_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```